# What does "Diversified" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I know what diversify means (https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/diversify?q=diversify)
but I'm not sure what kind of industry "diversified" is.

6. Diversified

· 188 billionaires

· 9% of the list

Source: https://www.forbes.com/sites/willyakowicz/2019/03/09/how-the-worlds-billionaires-got-so-rich/#3619bce46ae6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here **diversified** doesn't indicate any singular industry.

Some billionaires aren't involve in only one industry, they might have business related to various industries, thus there source of fortune can't be associated with one particular industry. So there source has been stated as **diversified**

Answer (score 0):

It means in different areas, different fields, in diverse fields. Billionaires from different areas.